# Is the geometric realization of a simplicial abelian groups is a topological group?

Tags: reference-request, simplicial-stuff

Reading

http://math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/SCR.pdf

I found the result that ask for but for commutative rings.

I'm looking for references of any of this facts.

Comment: Yes. This follows from the fact that geometric realization commutes with finite products, which means it sends models of any Lawvere theory (groups, rings, etc.) to models of the same Lawvere theory.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan This is more an answer than a comment right ?